# HTML: element in foreground shouldn't be block contents in the back when hovering with the mouse?

Tags: javascript, html, css

you know this problem. A link is in a container that is set behind a absolute positioned block element above it. In this case the link can't be clicked.

See for instance this example: http://jsfiddle.net/8VE3a/

I'm just curious, is there any way to make the container above not block a click event so that it "hits" the link underneath? The same question with `hover`? If I hover over the link I still want it's mouse-over state to be triggered!?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you are: http://jsfiddle.net/8VE3a/1/

```
pointer-events: none;
```

Answer (score 1):

depending on the situation you could change the z-index of your link items so that they appear above the background content:

CSS:

```
.some-class a{
    z-index: 5;
}
.background-div{
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Comment: Why someone voted down? If @matt need this to work even in IE, this answer is only possible way to achieve desired result.